# Eliminación de registros Many to Many Doctrine+Symfony2

Tags: symfony2, doctrine

Buen día/tarde/noche

Tengo el siguiente problema en un proyecto que estoy haciendo con symfony2:

Uso FOSUserBundle para hacer la gestión de usuarios (autorización y autenticación), ademas de eso manejo la cuestión de los grupos, el problema ocurre cuando quiero eliminar un usuario me sale el siguiente error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM grupo WHERE id = ?' with params [8002]:SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`acceso`.`grupo_usuarios`, CONSTRAINT `FK_461BB837FE54D947` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `grupo` (`id`))

La verdad he aplicado todas las configuraciones en la entidad de usuarios que manejo con relación al grupo, esta es mi ultima configuración:

```
class Usuarios extends BaseUser{
....

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Proyecto\AdminBundle\Entity\Grupo", cascade={"persist","remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="grupo_usuarios",
 *          joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *          inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *     )
 */
protected $groups;
....
}
```

Pero sin ningún resultado y generando el mismo error.

Nota:

1. He seguido la guía de grupos del fosuserbundle que tiene symfony:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/groups.html.

Agradeceria su ayuda.

Un saludo a la comunidad de stackoverflow en español.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola el problema aqui es que estas borrando registros de tablas relacionadas cierto ? Bueno lo que ocurre es que te dice que no puedes borra ese registro porque esta relacionado con otro, tienes que crear la query para borrar primero 1 y en el mismo controlador crear la query para borrar el otro, osea dos consultas y remove en el mismo controlador, algo así:

public function eliminarAction($id)
    {

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $consulta = $em->createQuery('SELECT ea FROM LetiSagcaBundle:EmpleadoAdiestramiento ea JOIN ea.empleado e 
                                    WHERE ea.adiestramiento = :id')
                   ->setParameter('id',  $id);
    $empleado_adiestramiento = $consulta->getResult();

    $em->remove($empleado_adiestramiento);
    $em->flush();


    $adiestramiento = $em->getRepository('LetiSagcaBundle:Adiestramiento')->find($id);

    $em->remove($adiestramiento);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_adiestramientos')

    );

}
```

Este me esta arrojando una excepcion y no esta funcionando pero es para que tengas una idea. Saludos desde Venezuela

Answer (score 1):

No se si sea más correcto que ponga esto como comentario, pero aún no tengo la reputación suficiente en el sitio para añadir comentarios, asi que me arriesgaré esperando que te sirva para resolver tu problema.
A partir de que el error te dice que no se puede borrar el usuario de la base de datos, me parece entonces que el error no tiene nada que ver con la entidad Usuario. El problema debe estar en la configuración de tu base de datos. Fíjate que acción tienes puesta en la opción 'On Delete'. Puede que tengas puesta la opción 'RESTRICT' y por esto no te esté dejando borrar el registro de la base de datos. O si puedieras poner una captura de pantalla del diseño que tiene tu tabla en la BD, para ver que pudieras tener mal, ya que parece que el error esta en la BD, y no en la entidad.